# Best OS for an old HP Netserver LH 6000/r Server?

Tags: linux

I've an old HP Netserver LH 6000/r server and would like to know which linux distribution will be best suited for it. We plan to use it as a development server (running tomcat instances, and some databases).

Best regards, Esteban.

Comment: A netbook with atom cpu would outperform it.. are you sure you really want to go through all this work, considering the low performance and the age of the hardware (ie reliability)?

Comment: Can I recommend a fireaxe? There is so much wrong with this question, I'm not sure where to start.  Unless you're running this same hardware in production (in which case you should run the same OS as that), you just need to sell this off for the scrap metal. You'll spend more on cooling and power for this than if you were to buy a G4-ish DL380 from ebay. But even that's a fail, because you should be buying matching hardware for your dev/staging environment as when you do your prod environment. "Practice like you're going to perform..."

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same distro you plan to use in your production environment. Hopefully you have plenty of memory in it, if not you could try running one of the pruned down distros like DSL but you are going to run into problems running Java/Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer. The server is indeed a very cheap one, that we  bought just for its price (less than a hundred box)... So we are looking for using it in a single project with only three developers involved. Hopefully we will be able to run a JDK decently!